# Using front_inserter instead of back_inserter

Tags: c++, iterator, std

guys!
I'm trying to understand the work of iterators, so in the code below,is it possible to change back_inserter to front_inserter without changing underlying data (structure). 
Could you,please,explain why. If change is possible consider its key idea.

```
int a1[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int a2[] = { 1, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> a3;
int a4[] = { 0, 2, 3, 6 };
std::set_difference(a1, a1 + 7, a2, a2 + 3, std::back_inserter(a3));
assert(std::equal(a3.begin(), a3.end(), a4));
```

Thank you all!

Comment: No, it is not possible. It requires a container that supports `push_front`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Excellent response :)

Comment: See my answer for how to use std::inserter to solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An insert iterator is simply an implementation of an iterator which inserts something in to a collection using standard mechanisms.  In the case of `back_inserter`, the insertion is done by calling the  `push_back()` method on the container.  Hence, in order to use `back_inserter`, the container must implement `push_back()`.

Likewise, with `front_inserter` the collection mush implement `push_front()`, which `vector` [does not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  Therefore, you can't use `front_inserter` on a `vector`.

`list` and `deque` both implement `push_front`, so if you were to use one of those rather than a `vector`, you could use `front_inserter`.

Comment: Well put, but feel free to copy my solution to take advantage of the preferred solution to the Ops original issue.

Answer (score 1):

No, but what you want is an inserter:

```
std::set_difference(a1, a1 + 7, a2, a2 + 3, std::inserter(a3, a3.begin()));
```

Comment: Although that is relatively inefficient.